# UIImagePickerController within existing UIPopoverController resizing issue on iPad

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am working on an iPad app where I have a button that generates a popover controller that I am populating with a specific view controller. Here is the button code that generates the UIPopoverController and loads it with a specific view (signUpListAddEditViewController):

```
-(void)addSignUpList:(id)sender {
    signUpListAddEditViewController = [[SignUpListAddEditViewController alloc] init];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:signUpListAddEditViewController];
    popover.popoverContentSize = signUpListAddEditViewController.view.frame.size;
    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    signUpListAddEditViewController.popover = popover;
}
```

Inside SignUpListAddEditViewController.m, I have several fields and a tableview. One of the fields is a UIButton where I display an image and allow the user to load a new image using this button. Since I am already in a popover, I swap the content controller with the UIImagePickerController. So far, so good.

```
-(void)takePicture:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:popupScreenSize animated:YES]; // popupScreenSize is a CGSIZE set to 500 x 900
    [popover setContentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

The view is swapped out with the imagePicker with the size remaining the same as the original view and I can see the various picture galleries (Camera Roll, Photo Stream, etc). Here is where it gets strange. As soon as I pick one of the galleries, the view is replaced with a thumbnail view of the pictures in that gallery AND THEN the view resizes to a much narrower width. The images are distorted and nearly impossible to select one of them.

I have tried setting [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSIZE animated:YES] prior to every access to the popover controller, with everything resizing properly EXCEPT the detailed image view? Any ideas where I can override the thumbnail image gallery view?

Here is the code for the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method where I again override the content size:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [thisList setThumbnailDataFromImage:image];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:popupScreenSize animated:YES];
    [popover setContentViewController:self animated:YES];
    listImageButton.imageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem as you described. It also crashes on weird times, sometimes when selecting an album. Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Same problem here. Presenting an imagePickerController inside an UIPopoverController. Root menu (Moments/Camera Roll) appears normally but when an option is selected, the view with the thumbnails is pushed without problems and AFTER transition ends, the cells suddenly shrink and grow again to initial state.